# Right to Left Scrolling Background Swift / Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have a scrolling background, but the background image appears to be "zoomed in" compared to the original image. The background scrolls just fine, but I'm not sure why the image is "zoomed in". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var blueBall:SKSpriteNode!
var backgroundImage:SKSpriteNode!
var backgroundImage2:SKSpriteNode!


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {



    self.view!.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(imageLiteral: "backgroundImage.png"))


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    blueBall = SKSpriteNode( imageNamed: "ball1111.png")
    blueBall.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    blueBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: blueBall.size.width / 0.85)

    blueBall.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    blueBall.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
   self.addChild(blueBall)
    blueBall.zPosition = 2



    backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backgroundImage.png")
    self.addChild(backgroundImage)
    backgroundImage.zPosition = 0
    backgroundImage.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    backgroundImage.size.height = self.size.height
    backgroundImage.size.width = self.size.width
    backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))


    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "backgroundImage.png")


    let shiftBackground = SKAction.moveByX(-backgroundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 9)
    let replaceBackground = SKAction.moveByX(backgroundTexture.size().width, y:0, duration: 0)
    let movingAndReplacingBackground = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([shiftBackground,replaceBackground]))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i<3; i++ {

        let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * i), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        background.size.height = self.frame.height
        background.runAction(movingAndReplacingBackground)


        self.addChild(background)




 }





}
```

Comment: you may need to show more code,  what is your scale mode? Also when do you create backgroundImage

Comment: I will update my post now with more code.

Comment: also I noticed you are using imageNamed:     "backgroundImage.png", which means you most likely are not properly conforming to retina rules,  which could also be a problem.  How is your images contained in your project?  Is it an atlas, an xcassets file, or an atlas inside xcassets?

Comment: No, I don't believe my backgroundImage currently conforms to retina rules and my images are contained in an Assets.xcassets folder.

Comment: Update: My backgroundImage wasn't in the Assets.xcassets folder. So after putting the image in the folder, the problem is solved! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: if you right click the xcassets folder, you will see an option to add sprite kit atlas.  Use that.  When you are calling an image just do it without the extension

Comment: Just added it, thank you for the tip! Any tips that can help make programming easier / more organized is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the image not being loaded correctly, so your numbers are off.  Basically by loading SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backgroundImage.png") with the png extension, you are loading the actual file, not conforming to any retina rules.  The width and height then would not be adjusted to handle this case.  If you use an atlas inside the xcassets folder, it will allow you to specify the graphics for all display sizes, and will pick the correct one that is supported by the device.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon please could you take a look at my similar question, I've been at it for quite a while. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072572/how-can-i-make-my-level-menu-scrollable-vertically