# How can I make my level menu scrollable vertically?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I have the following level Menu (as seen below). I would like to make it vertically scrollable, resulting in a total height double that of the screen (full scroll height). How can I achieve this?

[image]

Below is the code for the image above:

```
class LevelMenu: SKScene {


let levelButtonSize = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b1").size
let levelButton1: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b1")

let levelButton2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b2")
let levelButton3: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b3")
let levelButton4: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b4")
let levelButton5: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b5")
let levelButton6: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b6")
let levelButton7: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b7")
let levelButton8: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b8")

let levelButton9: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b9")
let levelButton10: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b10")
let levelButton11: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b11")
let levelButton12: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b12")

override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)
    let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
    backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(bg)

    let column1PosX = levelButtonSize.width*cDiff
    let column2PosX = levelButtonSize.width*cDiff + levelButtonSize.width*2.0
    let column3PosX = levelButtonSize.width*cDiff + levelButtonSize.width*4.0

    let row1PosY = self.frame.height - levelButtonSize.width*1.5
    let row2PosY = row1PosY - levelButtonSize.height - levelButtonSize.width*rDiff
    let row3PosY = row2PosY - levelButtonSize.height - levelButtonSize.width*rDiff
    let row4PosY = row3PosY - levelButtonSize.height - levelButtonSize.width*rDiff

    levelButton1.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y:  row1PosY)
    levelButton1.zPosition = 10
    self.addChild(levelButton1)


    levelButton2.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y:  row1PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton2)

    levelButton3.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y:  row1PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton3)

    levelButton4.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row2PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton4)

    levelButton5.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row2PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton5)

    levelButton6.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row2PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton6)

    levelButton7.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row3PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton7)


    levelButton8.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row3PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton8)


    levelButton9.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row3PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton9)

    levelButton10.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row4PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton10)

    levelButton11.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row4PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton11)

    levelButton12.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row4PosY)
    self.addChild(levelButton12)

}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Ron Myschuk's solution, the code below show's what I've been able to achieve and [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ5Ai.jpg) shows a .gif of the issue I am having currently, where the screen scrolls too much at the top of the menu.

```
class LMScene: SKScene {

let levelButtonSize = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b1").size
let levelButton1: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b1")

let levelButton2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b2")
let levelButton3: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b3")
let levelButton4: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b4")
let levelButton5: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b5")
let levelButton6: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b6")
let levelButton7: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b7")
let levelButton8: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b8")

let levelButton9: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b9")
let levelButton10: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b10")
let levelButton11: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b11")
let levelButton12: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b12")

let levelButton13: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b13")
let levelButton14: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b14")
let levelButton15: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b15")
let levelButton16: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b16")
let levelButton17: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b17")
let levelButton18: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b18")


private var scrollCell = SKSpriteNode()

private var moveAmtX: CGFloat = 0
private var moveAmtY: CGFloat = 0
private let minimum_detect_distance: CGFloat = 30
private var initialPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
private var initialTouch: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
private var resettingSlider = false

override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)


    scrollCell = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: 2*self.size.height - self.frame.width*0.24734))
    scrollCell.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    scrollCell.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    scrollCell.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(scrollCell)

    let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
    backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    self.addChild(backgroundImage)

    let column1PosX = levelButtonSize.width/2 + self.frame.width*0.14855
    let column2PosX = 3*levelButtonSize.width/2 + 2*self.frame.width*0.14855
    let column3PosX = 5*levelButtonSize.width/2 + 3*self.frame.width*0.14855


    let row1PosY = self.frame.height - levelButtonSize.height/2 - self.frame.width*0.24734
    let row2PosY = row1PosY - levelButtonSize.height - self.frame.width*0.24734
    let row3PosY = row2PosY - levelButtonSize.height - self.frame.width*0.24734
    let row4PosY = row3PosY - levelButtonSize.height - self.frame.width*0.24734
    let row5PosY = row4PosY - levelButtonSize.height - self.frame.width*0.24734
    let row6PosY = row5PosY - levelButtonSize.height - self.frame.width*0.24734

    levelButton1.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y:  row1PosY)
    levelButton1.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton1)


    levelButton2.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y:  row1PosY)
    levelButton2.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton2)

    levelButton3.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y:  row1PosY)
    levelButton3.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton3)

    levelButton4.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row2PosY)
    levelButton4.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton4)

    levelButton5.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row2PosY)
    levelButton5.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton5)

    levelButton6.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row2PosY)
    levelButton6.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton6)

    levelButton7.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row3PosY)
    levelButton7.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton7)


    levelButton8.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row3PosY)
    levelButton8.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton8)

    levelButton9.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row3PosY)
    levelButton9.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton9)

    levelButton10.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row4PosY)
    levelButton10.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton10)

    levelButton11.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row4PosY)
    levelButton11.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton11)

    levelButton12.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row4PosY)
    levelButton12.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton12)

    levelButton13.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row5PosY)
    levelButton13.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton13)

    levelButton14.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row5PosY)
    levelButton14.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton14)

    levelButton15.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row5PosY)
    levelButton15.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton15)

    levelButton16.position = CGPoint(x: column1PosX, y: row6PosY)
    levelButton16.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton16)

    levelButton17.position = CGPoint(x: column2PosX, y: row6PosY)
    levelButton17.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton17)

    levelButton18.position = CGPoint(x: column3PosX, y: row6PosY)
    levelButton18.zPosition = 10
    scrollCell.addChild(levelButton18)

}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

            self.scrollCell.removeAllActions()
            initialTouch = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)
            moveAmtY = 0
            initialPosition = self.scrollCell.position
        }
    }

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let movingPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)

        moveAmtY = movingPoint.y - initialTouch.y

        scrollCell.position = CGPoint(x: initialPosition.x, y: initialPosition.y - moveAmtY)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    checkForResettingSlider()
    yMoveActions(moveTo: -moveAmtY)
}

func checkForResettingSlider() {

    if resettingSlider { return }

    let scrollDif: CGFloat = (scrollCell.size.height - self.size.height) / 2.0

    if scrollCell.position.y > scrollDif {

        let move: SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: scrollDif, duration: 0.3)
        move.timingMode = .easeOut
        scrollCell.run(move, completion: { self.resettingSlider = false })
    }

    if scrollCell.position.y < -scrollDif {

        let move: SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: 0 - scrollDif, duration: 0.3)
        move.timingMode = .easeOut
        scrollCell.run(move, completion: { self.resettingSlider = false })
    }
}

func yMoveActions(moveTo: CGFloat) {

    let move: SKAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: (moveTo * 1.5), duration: 0.3)
    move.timingMode = .easeOut

    self.scrollCell.run(move, completion: { self.checkForResettingSlider() })
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with using a scene camera?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup shame on you for posting a 7 word "buzz word" comment with no explanation or direction on how to use it or where to go!

Comment: @ItsMeAgain shame on you for posting a question with no proof or indication that you actually tried to figure out this problem for yourself. There are dozens of examples on SO alone which show how to do this!

Comment: @RonMyschuk It was merely a question for the OP.  He may just need a reminder SKCamera is there.  If he has no idea what it is or how to use it, then he can respond and i will post an answer.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup sorry for not replying earlier. I am not really familiar with SKCamera I'm open to use to this approach

Comment: can someone please help me out with this.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this working

Comment: not sure where your problem is, RonMyschuk gave you the answer.  You group all of your buttons into 1 master SKNode, then you just move the master SKNode

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I followed RonMyschuk's solution and ended up with the problem I explained in the comments to his answer. I haven't  been able to get beyond this point

Comment: @ItsMeAgain I've not been too busy, I am not going to do all the work for you. You've not shown any code of attempts you have made to get this to work. All you are showing is some code laying out some sprites. Please re-read the second sentence in my answer. FYI, I spent a considerable chunk of time constructing my answer, and you didn't even mark it as "useful"...lol

Comment: @RonMyschuk I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that I use to scroll vertically, I've adapted it to fit your menu. It doesn't perfectly line up to all your items, but it'll give you somewhere to start. And it'll show you how to figure this out on your own.

> EDIT: I've updated the code use these funds instead. Still declare your buttons the same way but call my createMenu func to actually create the menu. It is looped so it auto adjusts if you change the number of menu items. the only thing you have to be aware of is; if you add or remove buttons change the array at the top of createMenu accordingly. Also adjust the padding variable to how much vertical space you want between the items

```
func createMenu() {

    let buttons = [levelButton1, levelButton2, levelButton3, levelButton4, levelButton5, levelButton6, levelButton7, levelButton8, levelButton9, levelButton10, levelButton11, levelButton12, levelButton13, levelButton14, levelButton15, levelButton16, levelButton17, levelButton18]
    let padding: CGFloat = 400

    let numberOfRows = CGFloat(buttons.count / 3)

    scrollCell = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: levelButtonSize.height * numberOfRows + padding * numberOfRows))
    scrollCell.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - self.size.width / 4, y: 0 - (scrollCell.size.height - self.size.height / 2))
    scrollCell.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    scrollCell.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(scrollCell)

//        let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
//        backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
//        self.addChild(backgroundImage)

    let column1PosX = scrollCell.size.width / 3 / 2
    let column2PosX = scrollCell.size.width / 2
    let column3PosX = scrollCell.size.width / 3 / 2 + scrollCell.size.width / 3 * 2
    var colCount = 0
    var rowCount = 0

    for button in buttons {

        var posX: CGFloat = column2PosX
        if colCount == 0 {
            posX =  column1PosX
        }
        else if colCount == 2 {
            posX =  column3PosX
            colCount = -1
        }

        let indexOffset = CGFloat(rowCount) * (levelButtonSize.height + padding)
        let posY = scrollCell.size.height - levelButtonSize.height / 2 - (indexOffset + padding / 2)
        button.position = CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY)
        button.setScale(0.5)
        button.zPosition = 10
        scrollCell.addChild(button)

        if colCount == -1 {
            rowCount += 1
        }
        colCount += 1
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        self.scrollCell.removeAllActions()
        initialTouch = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)
        moveAmtY = 0
        initialPosition = self.scrollCell.position
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let movingPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)

        moveAmtY = movingPoint.y - initialTouch.y

        scrollCell.position = CGPoint(x: initialPosition.x, y: initialPosition.y - moveAmtY)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    checkForResettingSlider()
    yMoveActions(moveTo: -moveAmtY)
}

func checkForResettingSlider() {

    let topPos: CGFloat = scrollCell.size.height - self.size.height / 2
    let bottomPos = 0 - (self.size.height / 2)

    if scrollCell.position.y > bottomPos {

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: bottomPos, duration: 0.3)
        move.timingMode = .easeOut
        scrollCell.run(move)
    }

    if scrollCell.position.y < -topPos {

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: -topPos, duration: 0.3)
        move.timingMode = .easeOut
        scrollCell.run(move)
    }
}

func yMoveActions(moveTo: CGFloat) {

    let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: (moveTo * 1.5), duration: 0.3)
    move.timingMode = .easeOut

    self.scrollCell.run(move, completion: { self.checkForResettingSlider() })
}
```

Comment: I implemented your solution but when I scroll to the top, it moves beyond the visible level buttons and when I scroll to the bottom it only shows have of the lowest row buttons. I added two rows to my level menu as in the image above so I set `scrollCell = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: 1.5*self.size.height))`. Also when I touch one of the buttons (in an attempt to scroll) it begins the level touched. How can I get scrolling the screen to be differentiated from tapping on buttons?

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with `checkForResettingSlider()` that's causing the behavior not too sure what it is though

Comment: I guess you've been quite busy. I've not been able to solve this, I am still having the same issue

Comment: thanks, though there are some issues with it that I've not been able to solve. It's truncating the top row. I am not sure why you reduced the scale, but I removed that line and I also made ScrollCell position (0, 0) since the first column was offscreen. This is a link to my current scrolling menu http://imgur.com/9w6AxwT

Comment: it was scaled because I don't have your images and the images I was using were too big

Comment: From my latest gif in my previous comment the top row is still getting truncated when scrolling

Comment: what's your scene anchorPoint set to?

Comment: my scene anchorPoint is (0.0, 0.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142631/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-itsmeagain).

Comment: can we please chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142631/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-itsmeagain

Comment: I sent you a message at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142631/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-itsmeagain. I am trying to space the x positions equally but having issues.

Comment: @ItsMeAgain you should post a new question so as to keep the questions focused and more relevant for others