# Why Does My UIScrollView/SubView Keep Showing Up When I Switch SKScenes?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, sprite-kit

So I'm having a problem with my UIScrollView/Subview. Whenever I click the "back" button in my shop scene, it goes to the main menu but the scroll view is still there. How can I fix?

Main Menu Screen Before Back Button is Clicked (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yVyc.png)

Shop Scene With Back Button located in the bottom right
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km3zi.png]

Main Menu Scene After Back Button is clicked
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT6Q0.png)

Code:

```
  var scrollView = UIScrollView()
  let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: frame)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height*4)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
   self.view?.addSubview(scrollView)
```

When I switch SKScenes the UIViews just stay there.

Comment: You should show some code, specifically where you add the scroll to the shopScene

Comment: @RonMyschuk I added some!

Comment: @RonMyschuk Are you sure there's no way for me to do this? Because I have tried doing the scroll view within SpriteKit and it didn't work for me. I had to use this instead

Comment: I didn't say there was no way to do this using UIKit. I just personally don't like mixing the 2. and have creating scrolling panels in Spritekit many times.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your UIScrollView to the SKView (not the scene). The Scenes are added to the SKview as well. When you switch the scenes the scroll view is still in the SKView.

This isn't really how you should be handling this. Personally I don't like mixing UIKit and Spritekit. Especially since it is quite easy to create a scroll panel in Spritekit. There are many examples in SO of how to create a scrolling panel in Spritekit [How can I make my level menu scrollable vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072572/how-can-i-make-my-level-menu-scrollable-vertically/43076308#43076308) (the downside is you will have to the scrolling in code yourself vs. UIScrollView doing it for you)

Normally when creating a game in Spritekit you create a Scene and it gets added to the SKView. You then create any game objects and add them to the Scene. That way when the Scene gets destroyed the objects will get destroyed with it.

If you have to create something in UIKit it gets added to the view but you will have to manually remove it from the view because destroying the scene will not affect it.

Comment: I have already tried using that and it causes even more problems within my game. So I can't automatically remove it from the view? @RonMyschuk